# Swift Encoding a JSON dictionary [String: Any], can't get rid of the quotes

Tags: swift, encoding, nsdata

We are grabbing some data from an API, which we decode into a `[String: Any]` dictionary.
We want to then take this dictionary, and mutate a value for a key `"$twitter_card"`.
Then we want to encode that back into `Data`, which we send back to the API.

```swift
print(seeEditResponseString)
guard let data = seeEditResponseString.data(using: .utf8) else {return}

if let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any], var dataDict = dict["data"] as? [String: Any] {

    let summary: Any = "summary"
    print(dataDict)
    dataDict["$twitter_card"] = summary
    print(dataDict)


    let url = URL(string: "https://api2.branch.io/v1/url?url=\(link)")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "PUT"

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["branch_key": EnvConstants.branchKey, "branch_secret": EnvConstants.branchSecretKey, "data": dataDict])
    request.httpBody = jsonData
```

Print statement before setting `"$twitter_card"`:

```
["~feature": TwitterShare, "$publicly_indexable": 1, "$one_time_use": 0, "~id": 881331908143151724, "~creation_source": 3, "~channel": twitter, "$og_description": HELLO WORLD, "$twitter_app_country": US, "$twitter_card": summary_large_image]
```

After setting `"$twitter_card"`:

```
["~feature": TwitterShare, "$publicly_indexable": 1, "$one_time_use": 0, "~id": 881331908143151724, "~creation_source": 3, "~channel": twitter, "$og_description": HELLO WORLD, "$twitter_app_country": US, "$twitter_card": "summary"]
```

Notice how before there aren't quotes in the value, but after there is.  We believe the API request is failing because of this, but can't figure out how to match the same data type on the request back.

EDIT: here is the response as a `String`:

```
"{\"data\":{\"$og_title\":\"Locker Room\",\"$publicly_indexable\":true,\"$deeplink_path\":\"open?link_click_id=881284646317326515\",\"~creation_source\":3,\"$locally_indexable\":true,\"$og_description\":\"HELLO WORLD\",\"$uri_redirect_mode\":\"2\",\"$identity_id\":\"880941693229513892\",\"$twitter_card\":\"summary_large_image\",\"$og_image_url\":\"https://bettylabs.io/lockerroom_logo_play_wide.png\",\"room\":\"91939938-1171-4e61-9ecf-5934b92298cf\",\"~feature\":\"TwitterShare\",\"url\":\"https://dummylit.com/CScjyeLyidb\",\"$twitter_title\":\"Disco Dev\",\"$fallback_url\":\"https://dummylit.com/room/91939938-1171-4e61-9ecf-5934b92298cf\",\"+url\":\"https://dummylit.com/CScjyeLyidb\",\"$ios_deeplink_path\":\"open?link_click_id=881284646317326515\",\"$canonical_identifier\":\"room/91939938-1171-4e61-9ecf-5934b92298cf\",\"$twitter_app_country\":\"US\",\"inviterId\":\"a5e7f4b2-580a-4661-aad3-2c78bb4a78c7\",\"$one_time_use\":false,\"~id\":\"881743970732394436\",\"~channel\":\"twitter\",\"$twitter_description\":\"Green Sock\"},\"type\":0,\"feature\":\"TwitterShare\",\"channel\":\"twitter\"}"
```

Comment: What does the JSON that you receive look like (before you decode)?

Comment: It is hard to help you if you do not provide the actual JSON you get from your API. `JSONSerialization` is a wrapper around Objective-C Serialization and it is much less Swifty than using the `Codable` protocol. You get a lot more control tthat way. Try to determin what type of Object you get out of the `Dict`, it might help to use the same type. However, `Codable` will provide you with so much more control that you will likely not use `JSONSerialization` any longer.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I have swapped our AFNetworking call to `responseString` from `responseData`, and printed out the String response.  @Patru if I go the `Codable` route wouldn't I need to fully define a struct, and then mutate it, and encode back? This dictionary could have 100 key/value pairs, it seems tedious to do it that way

Comment: The quotes are virtual. They are inserted to escape double quotes inside a string literal.

Comment: As you can see in your own print statement the quotes are there in the original (although they do not have to be, as long as your string does not contain whitespce). As I thought their _absence_ is a linearization artifact of whatever `NSObject` the `JSONSerialization` will return to you. Just do not bother with it any longer, at least as long as your JSON remains correct (i.e. can be linearized and delinearized consistently).